# Java JIT optimisation when using local fields

Tags: java, performance, jit, jvm-hotspot

I want to know the difference in performance between this two statement:

```
String cpt= null;
if(field1.getUser().getDepartment().getPosition() >0)
{
 cpt=field1.getUser().getDepartment().getPosition()+1;
}
```

And this one:

```
 String cpt= null;
    int position=field1.getUser().getDepartment().getPosition();
    if(position >0)
    {
     cpt=position+1;
    }
```

Does the JVM Hotspot make the optimisation of automatic assigning fields instead of calling the getField multiple times?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: it depends. In general, HotSpot employs [Common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) optimization, but there are many factors affecting whether the optimization applies to each particular case.

Comment: You should follow the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle anyway for larger expressions, then, you don’t need to speculate whether the JVM can or will optimize unnecessary repetitions.